# Initialized object returns null

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have a JComponent and it is declared in the body of the class and initialized in a method called on construction, but when I try to access the JComponent outside its initialization method from a different method inside the same class, it returns null. I'm not sure if the answer lies within the problem, but I can't seem to put my finger on just why this is happening.

```
class panelSets {

    public JPanel sell_buy() {
        buy = new monetaryField("Buy: ",0);
    }

    public JSplitPane tax_profit() {         //Called on initialization
        cost = new monetaryField("- Cost: ",1);
    }

    public void setCost() {
        this.cost.copper.setText("33");     //Here is where the error occurs
}

    monetaryField buy;
    monetaryField cost;
}
```

This is just a short snippet of my code where this instances lie. I can always post more if it's not here. Also, to clarify, the children of "cost" can't be accessed because "cost" is null to setCost().

Edit: To make everyone's day worse, "buy" is accessible from anywhere.

```
monetaryField(String s, int i) {
    label = new JLabel(s);
    gold = new singleField("gold.png");
    silver = new singleField("silver.png");
    copper = new singleField("copper.png");
    gold.addKeyListener(keys);
    silver.addKeyListener(keys);
    copper.addKeyListener(keys);

    if(i == 1) {
        gold.setEditable(false);
        silver.setEditable(false);
        copper.setEditable(false);
    }
    GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(this);             
    this.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
               layout.createSequentialGroup()
                  .addComponent(label)
                  .addComponent(gold)
                  .addComponent(silver)
                  .addComponent(copper)
            );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
       layout.createSequentialGroup()
          .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
               .addComponent(label)
               .addComponent(gold)
               .addComponent(silver)
               .addComponent(copper)
            ));
}
```

...

```
singleField(String s) {         //Outputs a JFormattedTextField with an icon at the end
    setOpaque(false);
    image = getImage(s);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not `copper` that's null?

Comment: Looks like `cost` is not `null` but `copper` is.

Comment: +1 to those above, and in any case this seems like a matter for simple debugging.

Comment: I took off the copper extension and placed "System.out.println(cost)", which returned null in setCost(), but not tax_profit(). Same for the copper child.

Comment: @Kyle If `cost` is indeed null, then the code you posted is not sufficient for getting any help. You haven't shown how you invoke `tax_profit` and modify `cost`.

Comment: What do you mean whn you say "_returned null in setCost()_"?  That doesn't make sense.  `setCost()` doesn't return anything (it's void).  You really need to learn to debug issues like this on your own.  As it stands, you're not even telling us any of the info we need to help.

Comment: **Are you getting an Exception?**  It's not clear based on your question.  If so, can we see the stack trace?  You need to provide a better description of what's happening.  Please explain what you expect to happen and what happens in stead.

Comment: tax_profit is a JSplitPane. It gets invoked when I add it to its parent. I am getting a NullPointerException when I try to access cost from any method other than tax_profit(). "Buy" is set up in the same way, yet it works.

Stack trace: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at omnitool.panelSets.setCost(panelSets.java:314)
at omnitool.panelSets.setFields(panelSets.java:293)
at omnitool.panelSets$1.keyReleased(panelSets.java:265)

Comment: You don't even access `cost` in `tax_profit()`... You **assign** it.  This question is a complete mess... The terminology you're using is creating a lot of confusion.  `tax_profit()` is a method, yet you're referring to it as if it's an object.  You don't even access `cost`, yet you say you do.

Comment: Checking if "copper" was null was one of the first things I did. When using System.out.println(cost) from tax_proft(), it returns type monetaryField. When using that same print call in setCost(), it returns null. tax_profit() is always called before setCost().

Comment: ... and he's still not posting the code pertinent to the problem. Voting to close this question as it's turning into little more than an exercise in frustration, in trying to convince the original poster to show the information that is needed, and in his ignoring this request. Kyle: you need to update your question. You need to post the code that underlies your problem.

Comment: This question **needs** to get closed.  The OP is wasting everybody's time.

Comment: Please show the line from your `MonetaryField` constructor that assigns a non-null value to the copper field.... Oh wait, there probably isn't one.

Comment: I'm sorry. Close it. This is just as frustrating for me. I'm sure I'll find out what it is eventually.

Comment: My guess is you're not assigning anything to the field named `copper` in the constructor for `MonetaryField`.

Comment: I posted the monetaryField constructor. All of it.

Comment: Can you also post the singleField constructor?

Comment: Okay, does singleField have a variable text with appropriate getters/setters? For that matter, caan you now **directly** test of copper is null? Do a simple test after `cost = new monetaryField("- Cost: ",1);`. Something like `if (cost.getCopper() == null) System.out.println("Copper is null");` will do, or however you access copper.

Comment: I think it's something else. I just moved the initialization of cost to sell_buy() and tax_profit() can't access cost without it. Something is wrong with tax_profit() and I just have to find what it is. Very misleading, that debugger. I think I'll find just what it is in a minute. I'm sorry for the misleading issue. Close this and downvote it, please.

Answer (score 3):

Check `monetaryField`'s constructor and make sure that `copper` is initialized in it, clearly at this point it's `null`:

```
this.cost.copper.setText("33");
             ^
    NullPointerException
```

Comment: Do we even know if the OP is getting a NPE??  As far as I can tell he hasn't told us anything that isn't confusing.

Comment: @jahroy you're right, I can't tell for sure. But in such a simple statement (and with such little information), it's hard to imagine a different error

Comment: I'm sorry to confuse. It throws nullpointerexception at that "error here"

Comment: @Kyle yup, that's what we suspected :) go fix `monetaryField`'s constructor, and make sure you do `copper = new ...` in there.

Comment: OK I'll go see what I can find.

Comment: No, copper is initialized fully. Read my updated code. It's really got me in a mess, because I know this isn't supposed to happen and something very small is terribly off.

Comment: @Kyle - You should edit your question to explain that it is in fact a _NullPointerException_.  That said - now that we know that, the solution is simple: either `cost` or `copper` is null.

Comment: `copper` is not in this class, you know ... it's in the `monetaryField` class, and it's in there that you forgot to initialize it

Comment: @Kyle - Either `copper` or `cost` is null.  Add a print statement in that method to find out which one it is (it would be better to use a debugger, but that's another discussion...).

Comment: I did. When using System.out.println(cost) from tax_proft(), it returns type monetaryField. When using that same print call in setCost(), it returns null. tax_profit() is always called before setCost().